# Switching from LSTM to Vanilla RNN for CharRNN and calculating accuracy

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, dimensions

I'm implementing this code taken from a YT tutorial on using LSTMcell for a character generation RNN. However, I'm trying to rewire it to function as a vanilla RNN. Simply replacing the `torch.nn.LSTMcell` with `torch.nn.RNN` while defining 'class.RNN' doesn't work either. When I do this, the evaluation part (see below) produces an error.

Lastly, how do I calculate the accuracy (along with loss) and surprisal of this model?

```
for iteration in range(NUM_ITER):

    hidden, cell_state = model.init_zero_state()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    loss = 0.
    inputs, targets = draw_random_sample(textfile)
    inputs, targets = inputs.to(DEVICE), targets.to(DEVICE)
    
    for c in range(TEXT_PORTION_SIZE):
        outputs, hidden, cell_state = model(inputs[c].unsqueeze(0), hidden, cell_state)
        loss += torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(outputs, targets[c].view(1))

    loss /= TEXT_PORTION_SIZE
    loss.backward()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-747a826cb63b> in <cell line: 5>()
     13 
     14     for c in range(TEXT_PORTION_SIZE):
---> 15         outputs, hidden, cell_state = model(inputs[c].unsqueeze(0), hidden, cell_state)
     16         loss += torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(outputs, targets[c].view(1))
     17 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    480                 input = input.unsqueeze(batch_dim)
    481                 if hx is not None:
--> 482                     if hx.dim() != 2:
    483                         raise RuntimeError(
    484                             f"For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got {hx.dim()}-D tensor")

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Full code:

```
import time
import random
!pip install unidecode
import unidecode
import string
import re

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

RANDOM_SEED = 123
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

DEVICE = torch.device('cpu')

TEXT_PORTION_SIZE = 200

NUM_ITER = 5000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.005
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 128

print('Device:', DEVICE)

string.printable

with open('shakespeare.txt', 'r') as f:
    textfile = f.read()

TEXT_LENGTH = len(textfile)

print(f'Number of characters in text: {TEXT_LENGTH}')

random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

def random_portion(textfile):
    start_index = random.randint(0, TEXT_LENGTH - TEXT_PORTION_SIZE)
    end_index = start_index + TEXT_PORTION_SIZE + 1
    return textfile[start_index:end_index]

print(random_portion(textfile))

def char_to_tensor(text):
    lst = [string.printable.index(c) for c in text]
    tensor = torch.tensor(lst).long()
    return tensor

print(char_to_tensor('abcDEF'))

def draw_random_sample(textfile):    
    text_long = char_to_tensor(random_portion(textfile))
    inputs = text_long[:-1]
    targets = text_long[1:]
    return inputs, targets

draw_random_sample(textfile)

class RNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, embed_size,
                 hidden_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        self.embed = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=input_size,
                                        embedding_dim=embed_size)
        self.rnn = torch.nn.LSTMCell(input_size=embed_size,
                                     hidden_size=hidden_size)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    
    def forward(self, character, hidden, cell_state):
        # expects character as size [batch_size, 1]
    
        # [batch size, embedding dim] = [1, embedding dim]
        embedded = self.embed(character)

        (hidden, cell_state) = self.rnn(embedded, (hidden, cell_state))
        # 1. output dim: [batch size, output_size] = [1, output_size]
        # 2. hidden dim: [batch size, hidden dim] = [1, hidden dim]
        # 3. cell dim: [batch size, hidden dim] = [1, hidden dim]

        output = self.fc(hidden)

        return output, hidden, cell_state
      
    def init_zero_state(self):
        init_hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size).to(DEVICE)
        init_cell = torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size).to(DEVICE)
        return (init_hidden, init_cell)

torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
model = RNN(len(string.printable), EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, len(string.printable))
model = model.to(DEVICE)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

def evaluate(model, prime_str='A', predict_len=100, temperature=0.8):
    ## based on https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/
    ## blob/master/char-rnn-generation/char-rnn-generation.ipynb

    (hidden, cell_state) = model.init_zero_state()
    prime_input = char_to_tensor(prime_str)
    predicted = prime_str

    # Use priming string to "build up" hidden state
    for p in range(len(prime_str) - 1):
        inp = prime_input[p].unsqueeze(0)
        _, hidden, cell_state = model(inp.to(DEVICE), hidden, cell_state)
    inp = prime_input[-1].unsqueeze(0)
    
    for p in range(predict_len):

        outputs, hidden, cell_state = model(inp.to(DEVICE), hidden, cell_state)
        
        # Sample from the network as a multinomial distribution
        output_dist = outputs.data.view(-1).div(temperature).exp() # e^{logits / T}
        top_i = torch.multinomial(output_dist, 1)[0]
        
        # Add predicted character to string and use as next input
        predicted_char = string.printable[top_i]
        predicted += predicted_char
        inp = char_to_tensor(predicted_char)

    return predicted

start_time = time.time()

loss_list = []

for iteration in range(NUM_ITER):

    hidden, cell_state = model.init_zero_state()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    loss = 0.
    inputs, targets = draw_random_sample(textfile)
    inputs, targets = inputs.to(DEVICE), targets.to(DEVICE)
    
    for c in range(TEXT_PORTION_SIZE):
        outputs, hidden, cell_state = model(inputs[c].unsqueeze(0), hidden, cell_state)
        loss += torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(outputs, targets[c].view(1))

    loss /= TEXT_PORTION_SIZE
    loss.backward()
    
    ### UPDATE MODEL PARAMETERS
    optimizer.step()

    ### LOGGING
    with torch.no_grad():
        if iteration % 200 == 0:
            print(f'Time elapsed: {(time.time() - start_time)/60:.2f} min')
            print(f'Iteration {iteration} | Loss {loss.item():.2f}\n\n')
            print(evaluate(model, 'Th', 200), '\n')
            print(50*'=')
            
            loss_list.append(loss.item())
            plt.clf()
            plt.plot(range(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
            plt.ylabel('Loss')
            plt.xlabel('Iteration x 1000')
            plt.savefig('loss1.pdf')
            
plt.clf()
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Iteration x 1000')
plt.plot(range(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
plt.show()
```

Comment: According to the error, somewhere you're passing the forward call of the model a `tuple`, and not a `tensor` into the hidden state (`hx`). Try to figure out where you might be passing a `tuple` instead of a `tensor`.